# Failing to alter the options using radio button

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

```
<!--Visual force page code-->

<apex:page controller="prgrm9cls"><apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >


<apex:pageblockSection >
<apex:selectRadio value="{!paymentstatus}" id="paymentstatus">
<apex:selectOption itemValue="Credit" itemLabel="credit card" ></apex:selectOption>
<apex:selectOption itemValue="Po" itemLabel="PO"></apex:selectOption>
<apex:selectOption itemValue="Invoice" itemLabel="Invoice"></apex:selectOption>
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="opid2" action="{!act}"/></apex:selectRadio></apex:pageblockSection>



<apex:pageBlockSection >

<apex:outputPanel id="opid2">
<apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!cardz}" columns="1">
<apex:pageblockSectionItem >
<apex:outputLabel value="Credit Card Name"></apex:outputLabel><apex:inputText value="{!creditname}"  />
</apex:pageblockSectionItem>
<apex:pageblockSectionItem >
<apex:outputLabel value="Credit CardNumber"></apex:outputLabel><apex:inputText value="{!CardNumber}" />
</apex:pageblockSectionItem>
<apex:pageblockSectionItem >
<apex:outputLabel value="CVV"></apex:outputLabel><apex:inputText value="{!CVV}" />
</apex:pageblockSectionItem></apex:pageBlockSection>

<apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!invoicess}">
<apex:outputLabel value="Invoice"></apex:outputLabel><apex:inputText value="{!Invoice}" />
</apex:pageBlockSection>

<apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!pozz}">
<apex:outputLabel value="Routing Number"></apex:outputLabel><apex:inputText value="{!porder}" required="true"/></apex:pageBlockSection></apex:outputPanel>

</apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:pageBlock>

 </apex:form></apex:page>
```

```
public class prgrm9cls {

    public String CVV { get; set; }

    public Integer CardNumber { get; set; }

    public String creditname { get; set; }

    public String porder { get; set; }

    public boolean pozz { get; set; }
 public String paymentstatus { get; set; }
    public String Invoice { get; set; }

    public boolean invoicess { get; set; }

       public boolean cardz { get; set; }

    public PageReference act() {

       if(paymentstatus == 'Credit'){
       cardz = true;
       invoicess = false;
       pozz = false;
       }
       if(paymentstatus == 'Invoice'){
       cardz = false;
       invoicess =true;
       pozz = false;
       }
       if(paymentstatus == 'po'){
       cardz = false;
       invoicess =false;
       pozz = true;
       }

       return null;
       }



    }
```

When i click on either one of the radio option then it should display it's relevant text. It was executing only for first two times and failing to work continously.

Can any one explain the mistake  have done

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i figured out the error. It is causing due the usage of 'Required' option in the panel. Removed that option at 'Routing Number'

```
<apex:outputLabel value="Routing Number"></apex:outputLabel><apex:inputText value="{!porder}" required="true"/>
```

which has resolved the issue.

Thanks,
Ravindra,
Salesforce Engineer.